# Any alternatives to Cucumberish which supports Swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, cucumber, xcuitest, cucumberish

Has anyone used BDD in XCUITest with Swift 4.2? Currently, we are using Cucumberish which does not support Swift 4.2, any suggestions on any alternatives to Cucumberish?

Comment: This is an outstanding issue on the GitHub repository about support for Swift 4.2 which indicates a work around or two for specific problems. See https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/Cucumberish/issues/114

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of functionality you are specifically looking for, but for BDD I use [XCT_Gherkin](https://github.com/net-a-porter-mobile/XCTest-Gherkin)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently exploring [CucumberSwift](https://github.com/Tyler-Keith-Thompson/CucumberSwift) -- so far, so good. So far, I find it much more convenient then Cucumberish. Let's see how it behaves later